# wordpress /woo commerce import script regularly calling wp-config.php causing super slow processing

Tags: php, wordpress, performance

I have written a product import application for many open-source shopping carts.

The core of the application is used for all carts, then I have used a separate class for importing products to the live shop specific to the shopping cart.

It works well on magento,osc,cre, and zen but with WordPress it really milks the server.

It is very resource-heavy, so much so that I can not even access a static .html file from the hosting account (through an HTTP request ).

The only thing I can work out is that the wp-config is called twice during the import process.

Will calling the wp-config.php twice really eat up resources? I must call this file to use the WordPress API to import the products.

I use:

```
include_once('../wp-config.php');
```

Comment: since you're using include_once(), the file would be loaded only once (hence the name)... look elsewhere for a simple include() that could be reloading it.

Comment: thanks very much for reading my question. I have looked but there is no other call. however i am calling it once with every ajax call (to import a product) i think its just slow because of wordpress architecture as all other carts bar magento is running fast (which again has a large architecture, but seems less than wordpress/woo

Answer (score 0):

you wrote include_once means file is included only once. Calling it with every ajax call is not issue. Rather you will require that. Script runs slow because of wordpress architecture. For each product import wordpress executes many queries. Maximum data of wordpress goes mainly in posts and post_meta tables. For each meta field one insert query will be executed which is why it works slowly.

You may write your own sql queries and use extended insert query style to add multiple meta tags which will be fast.